# Substituting all foreign characters in a string

Tags: excel, substitution

In Microsoft Excel, I have a cell that contains the name of a product I'm selling. That cell has a possibility of containing foreign accents in it. What I would like to do is replace the foreign characters with the nearest English equivalent. In this case, I create a formula with the following:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(G618,"ô","o")
```

Which when `G618` contains say "Nivôse", will return Nivose. However since Excel limits you from continually nesting `SUBSTITUTE()` functions on top of each other, I would like to know if there is another function or a way to write a function that would accomplish the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have my equivalences correct, the following User Defined Function should do the proper substitutions.  But you should check it.

**EDIT:**  I missed a few in my first try.  So now edited.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

**EDIT2:**  Modified to allow for replacements with two characters (eg: Æ with AE) or with no characters

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

**=ReplaceAccentedCharacters(A4)**

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function ReplaceAccentedCharacters(S As String) As String
    Dim I As Long

With WorksheetFunction
For I = Len(S) To 1 Step -1
    Select Case Asc(Mid(S, I, 1))
        Case &HC0 To &HC5
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "A")
        Case &HC6
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "AE")
        Case &HE0 To &HE5
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "a")
        Case &HE6
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "ae")
         Case &HC7
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "C")
        Case &HE7
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "c")
        Case &HD0
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "D")
        Case &HC8 To &HCB
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "E")
        Case &HE8 To &HEB
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "e")
        Case &HCC To &HCF
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "I")
        Case &HEC To &HEF
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "i")
        Case &HD1
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "N")
        Case &HF1
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "n")
        Case &HD2 To &HD6
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "O")
        Case &HF2 To &HF6, &HF0
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "o")
        Case &HD9 To &HDC
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "U")
        Case &HF9 To &HFC
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "u")
        Case &HD7
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "x")
        Case &HDD
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "Y")
        Case &HFD, &HFF
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "y")
    End Select
Next I
End With

ReplaceAccentedCharacters = S

End Function
```

Comment: This is so far working for me. If I may (and you don't have to edit your answer), can you give me an example of how I can replace a space with a hyphen?

Comment: @PaulWilliams The UDF is already checking every character.  So just add another Case statement.  Read about Select Case in VBA Help; and also the REPLACE function in Excel Help.  I happened to use HEX values instead of the ASCII values for the accented characters (because that's what the table I was looking at had); but for a **space** you can either the actual character, or the decimal or HEX values, as you please.  So your Case statement might look like **Case " "**  and the replace should be obvious.

Comment: Hmm... Mind explaining why this one isn't working? It's supposed to return nothing but the " is still there?

        Case &H22, &H93, &H94
            S = .Replace(S, I, 1, "")

Comment: What is the character code for the character that is not being replaced?

Comment: @PaulWilliams The function was designed to Replace one character with another.  When you replace a character with nothing, the counter gets messed up and you wind up trying to do ASC("") which is not valid.  So replace the " with something -- I suggest Chr(1) which won't appear in a normal string; and then, at the end do a VBA replace to remove the Chr(1).  See my response in your other thread for the code

Comment: It took me a moment but I think I got it now. Thanks

Comment: @PaulWilliams And you will also mess things up, with the above algorithm, if you try to replace one character with two, as you suggested in a fortunately rejected edit of my response.

Comment: As I just learned while using it. Either way I can still get around that. just have to replace with another single character or with nothing during the loop and using a post CASE statement

Comment: @PaulWilliams There's a simpler method to compensate, now that you've revealed that you want to replace some characters with nothing, and others with two letters -- just step through the string backwards.  I'll modify my response